# Could not find the module 'cChocoInstaller' when I try to compile my DSC configuration

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, dsc, powershell-dsc

I'm trying to get Chocolatey installed to manage packages on a a windows VM using Powershell DSC.

I've prepared my configuration file

```
Configuration chocandfirefox {
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChocoInstaller
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChocoPackageInstaller
       
    Node 'localhost' {

        cChocoInstaller installChoco
        {
            InstallDir = "c:\ProgramData\chocolatey"
        }

         cChocoPackageInstaller installGit
        {
             Name = "firefox"
            DependsOn = "[cChocoInstaller]installChoco"
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to compile it to a .mof, I'm told

```
> +     Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChocoInstaller
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Could not find the module 'cChocoInstaller'. At
> C:\Users\auser\Documents\PowerShell\DSC\Configuration_chocandfirefox.ps1:4
> char:5
> +     Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChocoPackageInstaller
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Could not find the module 'cChocoPackageInstaller'.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleNotFoundDuringParse
```

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental but I've worked through [docs on DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/quickstarts/website-quickstart?view=powershell-7.2) and [Chocolatey](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/integrations#powershell-dsc) and can't spot it.

Comment: It seems to work when I specify -Name  (The specific DSC resource name)
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco -Name cChocoInstaller
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco -Name cChocoPackageInstaller

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to import `cChoco`.

Looking at one of the examples provided in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/chocolatey/cChoco/blob/development/Examples/cChocoInstaller_cChocoInstallerExample.ps1), we can see:

```
Configuration InstallChoco
{
    Import-DscResource -Module cChoco
    Node "localhost"
    {
        cChocoInstaller InstallChoco
        {
            InstallDir = "c:\choco"
        }
        # ...
    }
}
```

They're using `cChocoInstaller` after only importing `cChoco`. `cChocoInstaller` is a resource within the module `cChoco`.